# AMD FirePro Series Gpu's for Ether

Tags: mining, ether, gpu

wanted to know if anyone has experimented with AMD's Firepro Gpu's for mining ether? if so what were there results? want to know if it is a practical investment or if regular gaming GPU's are the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is spend your money on a gaming card such as an r9 390 or r9 490 if you would like to stay with AMD. Firepro GPUs are simply not worth the extra cash and usually do not have the best cooling on them not to mention a lower hashrate on average.

Answer (score -1):

if your looking to a firepro or a gaming card what figures need to be higher to get a better hashrate ? it looks to me its only computing power so then the firepro would be better since they have much more computing power than a gaming gpu but if you say go with a gaming gpu its sounds like its not only computing power